# Importing Mapinfo .TAB files to AutoCad Map

Tags: mapinfo, import, autocad, autocad-map

It is any way to import Mapinfo files to Autocad Map with line and polygon style definitions cereated in Mapinfo?

Answer (score 2):

From Autodesk Map 3D Online Help:

**[Importing MapInfo TAB Files](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAP/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20Map%203D%202010%20User%20Documentation/HTML%20Help/files/WS01BF6EB99EFF304992FB8FBFFBBC6C93.htm)**

> You cannot import TAB symbol types directly. However, if you store the
>   symbol type information in a column in a DAT file, you can map each
>   symbol type to a block in the current AutoCAD Map 3D drawing. To do
>   this, prepare the TAB file by putting the name of the symbol type into
>   a field in the database. Prepare the AutoCAD Map 3D drawing by
>   creating similar symbols as blocks in the AutoCAD Map 3D drawing.
>   Then, during import, perform a point-block mapping and select the
>   check box to get the block name from data and select the symbol type
>   field you created.
>
> ...
>
> By default, object colors are imported to their closest ACI (AutoCAD
>   Color Index) color. To import object colors using RGB (True Color),
>   you must edit the *mapimport.ini* file.
>
> To change the default text justification setting for TAB, edit the
>   *mapforeignfileproperties.ini* file.

Comment: Now my question is how to put the name of the symbol type into a field in the database in Mapinfo?